# Testing Client/Server Interaction

Tags: ruby, testing

I have a client written in Ruby that allows you to type in a github url, such as rails/rails,
and the tracking server sends back a response, such as "now tracking rails/rails". Upon a change to the Github repo, the server sends a Desktop notification.

So it's quite simple, but I haven't been able to figure out how to automate the testing.
What I've tried so far is something like this:

1. spawn the server in a child process
2. IO.popen the client
3. Send the client strings (then hopefully the client passes them on to the server)
4. Reading from the io with io.readpartial(n) or io.gets
5. ???
6. PROFIT

When I get to step 3, it just hangs. How do I test client/server interaction in Ruby?

-Luke